# Nullspace of a Matrix and Linear Transformation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm having some issues to answer the following question:

Consider the subspace of S of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by columns of the matrix A $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Find the real numbers a, b, c for wich 
S = {(x, y, z) ∈ $\mathbb{R^3}$ : ax + by + cz = 0.

My tentative to solve the question was put the matrix in the echelon form and then solving the equation A.x = 0
Is this the right approach?

Comment: You need to add another column of zeros at the right and RREF the 3 by 4 matrix. The columns of your given matrix consists of vectors $x,y$ and $z$ respectively...

Comment: What do you mean by 'Find the real numbers a, b, c for which $S=\mathbb{R}^3$'? There are no such numbers, the matrix has determinant zero.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah! I wrote it wrong. Fixed it . Thank you

Comment: @imranfat What’s the point of adding a column of zeros outside of blind adherence to a formalism? No row operation will ever change its entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the **definition** of "null space of linear transformation A", the set of all $v$ such that $Av= 0$.  Personally, I wouldn't use matrices at all.

Applying this linear transformation to vector $(x, y, z)$ gives the vector

$$ (x+ y+ z, x+ 2y+ 3z, 2x+ 3y+ 4z)$$

If $(x, y, z)$ is in the null space that is $(0, 0, 0)$ so we must have

$$ x+ y+ z= 0,\quad x+ 2y+ 3z= 0,\quad 2x+ 3y+ 4z= 0.$$

From the first equation, $z= -x- y$.  Putting that into the second equation,

$$ x+ 2y+ 3z= x+ 2y+ 3(-x- y)= -2x- y= 0$$

so

$$ y= -2x, z= -x-(-2x)= x.$$

Setting $y= -2x$, $z= x$ in the third equation

$$2x+ 3(-2x)+ 4(x)= 2x- 6x+ 4x= 0, \,\,\forall x.$$

That is, the null space is the space of all vectors of the form $(x, -2x, x)= x(1, -2, 1)$.  The null space is the one dimensional space of vectors with basis ${(1, -2, 1)}$.

Comment: @tibL Thank man! Very well wrote anwser.
The official answer to this question says:
"Consider, for example, a = -1, b = -1, c = 1".
This vector (-1, -1, 1) is not in the nullspace of the columns, obsvly. Do you think that the answer to this question is wrong or we are missing something? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: ^ I just edited the latex, the solution is actually from @user247327, I wouldn't want to get undeserved credit ;)